# AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a ws client implemented using Axis2. Some times works, but some time occurs the error below:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:92)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: looks like you not getting a response back. Might be a network issue.

Comment: have you got the solution of this error ? please let me know because i am  also facing this today.

Comment: @RizN81 did you find the solution ? I am facing the same issue.